# ACE editor: how do i collapse folding on line 11 by code?

Tags: ace-editor

Lets say my ace has a folding on line 11. How do i trigger its collapse?

I dont understand how this weird folding works at all. There are several expand functions, but no collapse.

with session.getAllFolds() you obtain all folds, but none of them has a collapse function either. And with foldAll you fold all subfolds too (what for?).

When you click on a folding icon in the gutter, it just folds the one fold on its line - as I would expect it. But they have no events so i cannot find out how they do it either.

Answer (score 1):

folds are the hidden code ranges, arrows in the gutter are the fold widgets only

you can use `editor.session.$toggleFoldWidget(row, {})` to toggle it's open state https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/fbe3b69b8f5329a0e420a58231cdbe69fd0c5180/lib/ace/edit_session/folding.js#L768